# Excluding a visual studio project from compilation for TeamCity

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm using TeamCity build server, but one of my projects is a WiX project, I don't need TeamCity to compile it. I tried to exclude the project from visual studio Configuration Manager, and the project is excluded from build in Visual Studio, but TeamCity keeps trying to build that project.

Anybody knows why is this happening?

Comment: I know it's the stupid-obvious question but allow me to ask it anyway. What configuration is your TeamCity build running (Release|Any CPU?) and are you 100% sure that that's the configuration you've excluded the project from in Visual Studio. Most of the problems I see like this are because VS defaults to Debug but TeamCity is running Release.

Comment: Yes, the configuration in TeamCity is Release|Any CPU. The strange thing is when I change something in Configuration Manager I compare the .sln with the previous git version and it doesn't seem to change at all.

Comment: I have re-checked all the settings in Configuration Manager, and it's working now. Thank you.